# What are the differences between accessing Exchange email from your iPhone via IMAP vs ActiveSync (besides push notifications)?

Tags: iphone, email, exchange, imap, activesync

Aside from push notifications, what are the differences between accessing Exchange email from your iPhone via IMAP vs ActiveSync?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was working yesterday, so I'll tell you what was good ;)

1. List item
2. You can say "only store xxx days" of mail on your phone.
3. Calendaring works well.
4. If you have Exchange 2007+, your searches can go through the whole of the messages on the server, not just what's on your phone.

There's probably some more good things, but our firewall is interfering at the moment so I might have to go back :(